# Heading h1. Only content, or content + sidebar?

Tags: title

Where better to place the article title?

1.
[image: title content + sidebar]

2.
[image: title content]

Comment: What do you mean by 'better'? Better for what/who?

Comment: For readability of textual information. I'm sorry, I can not express it. I think you understand :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It depends whether the sidebar is related to the header or not.

In your first example, the sidebar seems to be related to the title.

In your second example, the sidebar seems to be an independent sidebar.

---

[image]
[image]

---

Take a look at the [Gestalt principles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gestalt_psychology).  They can give you some clue about how you can arrange your page to give the correct impression of the underlying structure.  Also lots of examples [here on UX.SE](https://ux.stackexchange.com/search?tab=relevance&q=Gestalt%20principles).

Comment: _"It depends whether the sidebar is related to the sidebar or not."_ - don't you mean "It depends whether the sidebar is related to the **content** or not." ?

Comment: @L.Möller  Thanks!  Should have been "related to the _header_".